# Netty 4 SSE update events

Tags: java, netty, server-sent-events

Im trying to create a netty based server to use [SSE especification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventSource) on client
First I create a handler(NotifyHandler) that extends from SimpleChannelInboundHandler, and extends from my own Pub system, when a notification arrives at onNotificationRecibed is written on context output channel.

```
private ChannelHandlerContext context = null;
private Publisher p = null;

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
    this.context = ctx;
    HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1,
            HttpResponseStatus.OK);
    HttpHeaders headers = response.headers();
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/event-stream");
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.Names.CACHE_CONTROL, "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.Names.PRAGMA, HttpHeaders.Values.NO_CACHE);
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.Names.TRANSFER_ENCODING, HttpHeaders.Values.CHUNKED);
    ctx.writeAndFlush(response);
    Pub.getInstance().suscribe(this);
}

@Override
public void onNotificationRecibed(String type, Map<String, Object> data) {
    context.writeAndFlush("event:"+type);
    context.writeAndFlush("data:"+data.toString());
    context.flush();
}
```

On the initializer:

```
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
    pipeline.addLast(new HttpRequestDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast(new HttpResponseEncoder());
    pipeline.addLast(new NotifyHandler());
}
```

I can´t make it work, i trying to find some examples or usages on this streams but nothing seems to work. Anyone can point me on the right direction?. Sorry for my english, and thanks for your time.

Comment: can you give some more details on what not works ? Also you should add a ChannelFutureListener to the ChannelFuture returned by writeAndFlush() and see if the future is failed.

Comment: Thanks Norman, the problem is that client side is not receiving any data. Ill try with ChannelFutureListener and tell my results.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @MPazik's suggestion, as you're using `HttpResponseEncoder`, you will need to write `HttpContent` to the `ChannelHandlerContext`. For example:

```
@Override
public void onNotificationRecibed(String type, Map<String, Object> data) {

    final StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder(1024); // 1kb
    msg.append("event:").append(type).append("\n");
    msg.append"data:").append(data.toString().append("\n\n"));

    final ByteBuf buffer = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(msg.toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    context.writeAndFlush(new DefaultHttpContent(buffer));    
}
```

All of the classes above are either standard JDK or Netty.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. As it is described in [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-eventsource-20091029/#event-stream-interpretation), each field has to be separated by new line and each message by another new line.

```
@Override
public void onNotificationRecibed(String type, Map<String, Object> data) {
    context.writeAndFlush("event:" + type + "\n");
    context.writeAndFlush("data:" + data.toString() + "\n\n");
    context.flush();
}
```